# What is Delta key in SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know that `Delta key` is a column in SQL table that should be of `datetime` type. But what is the purpose of Delta key?

Comment: I've never heard of "delta key". Your question makes it sound like it's a well known concept, but it's not (at least, for me)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing like Delta key in SQL Server for sure. If you will check the MSDN you can confirm this. You might take a look at [SQL Delta](https://www.sqldelta.com/index?page=whatissqldelta) which I guess you might be looking for.